# How do I detect non-printable characters in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm just wondering if there is a method in .NET 2.0 that checks whether a character is printable or not – something like `isprint(int)` from standard C.

I found `Char.IsControl(Char)`.

Could that be used for this purpose?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "Printable". Is "Coöperate" printable?  Is "協力する"?

Comment: Since the umlaut and the Chinese (?) characters are displayed on my screen I'd consider them "printable"—of course!

Comment: Then you should uncheck JWL_'s answer because it says both are not "printable".

Comment: This does need a better definition. Even assuming that we consider control characters non-printable and whitespace characters printable, is the [zero-width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) printable or not?

Answer (score 45):

You might want to use [`Char.IsControl(Char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440.aspx).  That is what I'm using.  You definitely do not want to use the `<0x20` method because any non-latin character and most non-english characters will be above 127.

Comment: In addition to control characters, you may also wish to exclude `0x2028` and `0x2029`. Many systems also regard them as non-printable although they are not classified as control characters. These characters can be filtered by `UnicodeCategory.LineSeparator` and `UnicodeCategory.ParagraphSeparator` respectively.

Comment: This will remove the carriage return and line feed characters. Do not use this to check for printable characters or it will remove all the newlines in your text.

Answer (score 26):

If by *printable* you mean renders *something* - even if that something is *blank space* (whitespace), **[negating] `Char.IsControl()` alone is *not* enough to determine if a character is printable**.

- It isn't enough even in the single-byte `U+0000` - `U+00FF` Unicode range (which is compatible with ASCII / ISO-8859-1), because the ASCII whitespace characters other than the space character are also classified as control characters, so that `Char.IsControl('\t')` and `Char.IsControl('\n')` report true as well.
- Beyond the single-byte range, there are other categories of non-rendering characters that must be recognized.

---

A solution for the **single-byte `U+0000` - `U+00FF` Unicode range (which is compatible with ASCII / ISO-8859-1)**:

```
  // Sample input char.
  char c = (char)0x20; // space

  var isPrintable = ! Char.IsControl(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c);
```

---

An ***approximation* of a solution** for ***all* Unicode characters**:

Sadly, there is no simple solution that is complete:

- A fundamental limitation of a `Char`-based test is that type `Char` can only represent characters up to code point `U+FFFF`, i.e., only characters in the so-called BMP (basic multi-lingual plane). Characters outside the BMP - with higher code points - must be represented as *two* `Char` instances (so-called surrogate pairs).
- The `UnicodeCategory.PrivateUse` category of characters, as the name suggests, is not standardized; for instance, `U+F8FF` on macOS contains the Apple symbol, whereas it is undefined on Windows. So it *may* contain printable characters, and you'd have to determine dynamically whether they are printable.
- The `UnicodeCategory.Format` category *mostly* contains non-rendering characters, but there are exceptions - see [this table](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm).

  - You could hard-code these exceptions for a given version of the Unicode standard, but that is cumbersome and may become obsolete over time.

Thus, the following code assumes that *all* characters in `UnicodeCategory.PrivateUse` and `UnicodeCategory.Format` are printable, which, means that at least some characters will be misclassified.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

// ...

  // Sample input char.
  char c = (char)0x20; // space

  // The set of Unicode character categories containing non-rendering,
  // unknown, or incomplete characters.
  // !! Unicode.Format and Unicode.PrivateUse can NOT be included in
  // !! this set, because they may (private-use) or do (format)
  // !! contain at least *some* rendering characters.
  var nonRenderingCategories = new UnicodeCategory[] {
    UnicodeCategory.Control,
    UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned,
    UnicodeCategory.Surrogate };

  // Char.IsWhiteSpace() includes the ASCII whitespace characters that
  // are categorized as control characters. Any other character is
  // printable, unless it falls into the non-rendering categories.
  var isPrintable = Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ||
    ! nonRenderingCategories.Contains(Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c));
```

Comment: I've been writing in C# for over 15 years and until today I thought that `Char.IsControl('\t') == false`. [TIL](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TIL), thank you! (And now I shudder to think of all the subtle bugs I've unwittingly introduced to the world because of that assumption).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `Char.IsControlChar()` there are several other functions that can be used to determine what category a given char value is:

- `IsLetter()`
- `IsNumber()`
- `IsDigit()`
- `IsLetterOrDigit()`
- `IsSymbol()`
- `IsPunctuation()`
- `IsSeparator()`
- `IsWhiteSpace()`

If what you have is a "traditional ASCII text" file, and you want to use supplied functions, the expression:

```
(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) || Char.IsPunctuation(ch) || Char.IsSymbol(ch) || (ch==' '))
```

should work.

Now, if you are working with Unicode, you are opening a can or worms. Even back in the day, whether a space is printable or not printable was open to interpretation (hence the `isprint()` and `isgraph()` functions). See [this related question and answers about "printable" unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters).