# Is there a consensus about printable UTF8 characters (to be used for a username)?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

In my chat app [TalkTalkTalk](https://github.com/josephernest/talktalktalk), for usernames, I allowed alphanumeric characters only (A-Z, a-z, 0-9):

```
username = re.sub(r'\W+', '', username)        # regex to keep alphanumeric only
```

This is a bit too restrictive because UTF8 characters are useful in many cases (people who have a name with another alphabet than `latin`, etc.). Now I would like to allow these useful UTF8 characters from other alphabets, and even things like ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢. (Why not?)

But I don't want :

- all kind of whitespaces, all kind of newlines (`&#10;`)
- malicious characters that look like empty zero-width char : http://unicode-table.com/fr/200D/
- etc. and more generally every character that could make that `userA<malicious_char>` looks like real `userA`.

**Which are the printable UTF8 characters?** (to be used in a username)

**How to filter them with a regex, for example in Python?**

*Note: This question is about finding a regex to filter them, so it's not a duplicate of some linked questions.*

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer / less opinion-based.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the range of Unicode Printable Characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters)

Comment: @Goyo it's linked, but this question here is about finding a regex to filter such a string, and the duplicate is not about this. Thanks btw tor the link.

Comment: You could consider allowing *any* character, but require the [`Unidecode`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) representation to be unique.

Comment: @MarkRansom nice idea, do you see how to do that?

Comment: I presume you have a database where you keep usernames? I know nothing about your app so I can't give you any specific advice, and it would be beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: You should take a look at the Unicode properties for characters ([Character Properties](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch04.pdf), chapter 4 of the Unicode standard).  From there, you should decide which properties are acceptable for use in a user name, and then accept only those characters that match your chosen set of properties.

Comment: Have a look at Unicode [General Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category). You probably want to exclude Separator and Other, and only allow Letter, Mark, Number, Punctuation, and Symbol.

Comment: @nwellnhof Nice idea. Would be interesting to find a regex for this...

Comment: It should be possible with the [`regex` module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties). The regex would look like `(\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{S})+`. But there are other issues you should consider like normalization, Zalgo text, or characters from different scripts with the same graphical representation (Cyrillic A vs. Latin A, for example). This really is a broad question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use flag `re.UNICODE` and unicode in regex expression, \u200b is not technically defined as whitespace

**python 2.7 and 3**

```
import re
username = u'My \u200bNick \u2602 \u263b \u200c '
white_chars = ['\s', u'\u200b',u'\u200c']     #etc
regex_str = '[' + ''.join(white_chars) + ']'
regex = re.compile(regex_str, flags=re.UNICODE)
regex.sub("", username )
print ( regex.sub("", username ) )
```

you get

```
u'MyNick\u2602\u263b'
MyNick☂☻
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this allow ❤ ☀ ? I would like those characters to be allowed.

Comment: I had misunderstood, fixed in post

Comment: What happens if `&#10;` is in the input string? i.e. `\u000A` or other non-printable char? It seems that there are many many non printable char: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770259/1422096

Comment: for example `\u200c` zero width non-joiner, etc .... I would use a list