# I need a list containing all the printable characters

Tags: python, list, character, ascii

I need list containing all the printable characters. I’ve already tried with ASCII but there aren’t any accented characters.

Do you how can I find one for Python.

Thanks

Comment: Define "printable"?

Comment: @hansolo Those are just the printable ASCII characters, which is a very small set of all printable characters.

Comment: @chepner Okay. Then maybe we need a better description of `printable`, i guess

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters help?

Comment: @hansolo Absolutely. The mention of accented characters immediately rules out just printable ASCII characters, but there are more extreme cases. For example, neither U+1F1FA nor U+1F1F8 would probably be considered printable in isolation, but together they should produce a single US flag glyph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this you can get 1,114,112 different characters. If you're looking for common accented letters you will find the in the first few hundred elements of this list.

```
characters = [chr(i) for i in range(1114112)]
```

```
[...,
 'ϗ',
 'Ϙ',
 'ϙ',
 'Ϛ',
 'ϛ',
 'Ϝ',
 'ϝ',
 'Ϟ',
 'ϟ',
 'Ϡ',
 'ϡ',
 'Ϣ',
 'ϣ',
 'Ϥ',
 'ϥ',
 'Ϧ',
 'ϧ',
 ...]
```

Comment: Not every codepoint is printable - or even a character: some are accents, for example.

Comment: If OP is looking for accents I think he will find what he needs in this list. I'll wait for some feedback from him. He might simply be looking for a more comprehensive list than just the ASCII, and he will definitely find the desired characters from my answer.

Comment: Or perhaps you can define character for me?

Comment: @NicolasGervais That's why we have comments on the questions, to ask for such clarifications.

Comment: This creates a list of *all* Unicode characters, with no regard to whether they are printable or not, so it does not answer the question.