# Text test on IWebElement using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have difficulty in an if test where I wan't to test if the text of my element is equel to a string.
I'm doing it like this :

```
WebElement vote1 = chromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@data-website-id=\"4\"]");
Console.WriteLine(vote1.GetAttribute("text")); 
if (vote1.GetAttribute("text").Equals("Vote N°1 [1H30]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Votable");
    chromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@data-website-id=\"4\"]").Click();
}
```

But while doing this my console is showing me this : 
[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgkRl.png)

Because the first writeline give me the exact same text that in the equals, I don't understand why the if is false.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried with trimmed text that you got using `getAttribute`, to rule out if there are any white spaces?

Comment: Not sure if StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase  function will help you because your string is having special character. You can refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280155/c-sharp-string-comparison-fails-for-string-having-special-character-in-it for more details

Comment: I finally was able to make it work by checking if my vote1 text had the string Vote using the Contains() function. I think it's not the best way but it worked fine. I will go check your answer to make a proper code thanks.