# Remove control characters in string programatically

Tags: c#, string, hex

i want to remove all control characters from 0x00 to 0x1F.

I thought i would do it like that:

```
string x = "\x1BTEST";

for (string stringHex = "00"; !stringHex.Equals("1F"); stringHex = (int.Parse(stringHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) + 1).ToString("X2"))
{
    x = x.Replace("\\x" + stringHex, "");
}
```

The double escape blows it. Ok. But how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing hidden characters from within strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
x = new string(x.Where(c => (int)c >= 0x1F).ToArray());
```

Comment: I love LINQ. However I struggle so much to apply it since i learned C# 1.0 and 2.0 and just think in old fashioned way of programming.
But thanks for the cool solution.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can remove control characters:

```
string input = "\u002Some Text";
string output = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
```