# Double.Parse fails for "10.00" retrieved value

Tags: c#

The screenshot sums up the problem:

[image]

I have no control over the retrieved value. It comes in with some funky format that I can't figure out and the parsing fails even though it looks totally normal. Typing the value in manually works just fine.

How can I "normalize" the retrieved value so `Decimal.Parse` does not fail?

For reference, here is the string that fails (copied and pasted):

"‎10.00"

Comment: that shouldn't fail to parse

Comment: which culture is it of your machine?

Comment: From PowerShell: `"‎10.00".Length` returns `6`. Well well, could there be some sort of hidden character? Yes of course. Your string starts with [`U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). If your user is supposed to be able to enter that, some kind of normalization may be needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing hidden characters from within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings)

Comment: @Rahul Try it yourself. https://dotnetfiddle.net/pi5xZq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have some kind of special character hidden in the string you are retrieving.

Try this:

```
Double.Parse(Regex.Replace(decimalValue, @"[^0-9.,]+", ""))
```

You might need to add using statement for `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M1cFWi

Comment: You are welcome. I forgot to mention I was using this for a variable that would only get positive values. If you are going to receive negative values as well, change your regex to @"[^0-9.,]+-" (note the added -)

Comment: The @"[^0-9.,]+-" is a nonsense and anyway the whole approach is not a good idea. It changes non-number strings like AW57 into numbers (57) and numbers into different numbers (like 1E7 into 17). It changes the input in rather unpredictable way, making the whole program unreliable.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek My use case is specific enough where that is not a concern.

Comment: @SabrinaFernandezVazzino Are you sure about the `+-`? To the best of my knowledge the `+` means "one or more", nothing to do with positive numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @"[^0-9.,-]+"

Answer (score 6):

First I would check your regional settings to eliminate anything as simple as a difference in expected decimal separator.

If that draws a blank then if the string `10.00` parses successfully then a string that *looks* like `10.00` but which fails to parse cannot actually *be* `10.00`.

Inspect and determine the character code of each character of the string and confirm that it really is `10.00` and not some exotic Unicode that has the same appearance but which is actually different (which may also include characters which are not even visible when displayed).

Comment: The regional settings are fine. It looks like there is a null character at the beginning. `input.Replace("\0", string.Empty);` does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace only the one problematic character, that is the safest option:

```
s = s.Replace("\u200E", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

As Jeroen Mostert mentioned in a comment, there is a non-printed character in your `decimalValue`.

This is a similar question which should help you deal with that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259355/7636764

Edit:

Using the the `string output = new string(input.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());` part of the solution, but also include in `|| char.IsPunctuation(c)` after IsDigit will get your desired result.

Comment: Trying that now.

Comment: Did you also try the IsLetter || IsDigit optional solution in that post?