# Eventhough two strings are same , C# .net core is not identifying as same

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, string-comparison, appsettings

I found this issue in asp.net core. I have two strings alpha numeric, all upper cases, and no spaces either in the middle or ends.

I am getting one string from `appsettings.json` and other assigning locally. When I compare those two strings, the application is showing they are not the same.

```
string stringFromAppSetting = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettingValue");

string string_Local = "1B4D3A3C8F63DBE";
bool? areTheySame=null;
if (stringFromAppSetting == string_Local )
{
    areTheySame = true;
}
else
{
    areTheySame = false;
}
```

I also tried `stringFromAppSetting.Equals(string_Local)`. It still shows they are not equal. I used notepad++ to check if they are different but I found that they are same.

Can somebody please suggest the possible cause.

Comment: What is the value of `stringFromAppSetting`?

Comment: 1B4D3A3C8F63DBE

Comment: Easiest way is to use for loop, and see what character is not same.

Comment: utf-8 vs. utf-16?

Comment: Make sure the Json file is saved as utf-8

Comment: @Doug strings don't have encodings. There is some hidden character probably

Comment: Try `if(stringFromAppSetting.Trim().ToUpper() == string_Local.Trim().ToUpper())`

Comment: @FortyTwo As you can see it is just the string I provided. there is no space or any other ascii value. It is that string

Comment: @FortyTwo already tried that

Comment: Is one null-terminated, and the other not?

Comment: Can you share your app.config?

Comment: are you verifying that you are actually reading the value for stringFromAppSetting? Meaning: are you putting breakpoints and checking the value?

Comment: @JonP already tried ..:)

Comment: @DaniDev .. yes that is what i am doing . I am doing this because thestring I was receiving from the config file was not being accepted as a secret key.

Comment: Have you tried a length comparison? Just to double check there is nothing hidden in the middle of that pesky config string. (deleted previous comment as was similar to @FortyTwo)

Comment: @JonP You are correct. There are 22 characters in the string from appsetting . That means 7 hidden characters

Comment: Impressive! 7 additional hidden characters in what appears to be a 15 character string. I was expecting one or two, not one-in-two.

Comment: On a side note, I disagree with the current votes to close on this. Code is provided as much a possible, any issues with the config file would likely be lost in a copy and paste. Also the problem is not due to a typographical error as such. The question may have merit for future readers who have similar issues in config files.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your response. For some reason, lot of hidden characters were present when string was received from appsettings.json file.After adding a logic to remove hidden character, it worked like a charm....

[Removing hidden characters from within strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings)

Comment: If you have hidden characters then these are from your appsettings.json file. It is not C# that is adding these chars, it is you

Comment: That might be very true.

Comment: 7 additional "hidden" chars where you expect to be 15 chars is really indicating you have choosen the wrong encoding for the file.

Comment: I am not saving the file with special encoding technique. This is a config file in asp.net core project. I am using VS 2017 if that helps.