# Delete extra sign from value string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, trim

When copy DEC value from win calculator have an extra sign in the start and the end of a string.
"‭1206462665545088‬" != "1206462665545088"

[image: Hex view]

and string.Trim() does not remove them.

Why Trim does not remove whitespace character?
How else to remove these signs?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings

Comment: Tried a little since, I was wondering why .IsControl didn't return true https://dotnetfiddle.net/ithLxG

Comment: JIC  `string.Equals(wrongStr, correctStr, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == true`. Not sure ow it works though =)

Comment: How are you copying "DEC value from win calculator" exactly? Why are you showing a memory dump? `String.Trim` only removes whitespace characters - why do you think "extra sign" (whatever that means) are whitespace?

Comment: Can you show the code? How do you read the Clipboard?