# Clearing unwanted hex characters with/without regex in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, hex

I have to clear hex characters from exception message in a better way. For now it works replacing characters manually which seems total disaster like this :

```
            var clearedStr = str.Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x01), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x02), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x03), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x04), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x05), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x06), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x07), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x08), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x0B), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x0C), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x0E), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x0F), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x10), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x11), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x12), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x13), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x14), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x15), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x16), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x17), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x18), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x19), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x1a), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x1b), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x1c), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x1d), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x1e), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x84), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x86), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x87), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x88), "")
            .Replace(Convert.ToString((char)0x89), "");
```

The message for example like this with hex characters :

[image: some of these characters]

Actually I wrote a regex but it works for hex character like 0x1e, but not for its equivalent :

But i need to find these characters, not hex equivalent :

"","‘","ƒ","","","’","","š","ˆ","‰","Š","‹","Œ","","„", "†", "‡"

Same characters with their symbols :

"RS: , PU1 : ‘, NBH : ƒ, US : , ESC : , PU2: ’, GS : ,
SCI: š, HTS: ˆ, HTJ : ‰, VTS : Š, PLD : ‹, PLU: Œ, SUB :, IND: „, SSA: †, ESA : ‡"

The regex is that I wrote :

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-9%5dx%5b0-9A-F%5d&i=0x1e+0x91+0x1c+0x83

Also, I need to cover all of this kind of chracters, not a bunch of them.

[image: example of characters]

Comment: ASCII Encoding will remove all non printable characters.

Comment: @jdweng that's not true. ASCII contains a bunch of non printable characters, Line Feed (0x9) comes to mind as well as [a bunch more](https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html)

Comment: How about this.. check this regex.
[0-9]x[0-9A-Fa-f].+?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253247/how-do-i-detect-non-printable-characters-in-net

Comment: @jdweng i try with online encoder. i need to show this data so if i encde this text, i need to decode to show message to user. so when i decode probably it turns to initial character again. but still i need to test it in detail.

Comment: @MindSwipe : A linefeed is a printable character since it causes the printer to move to next line.  A Bell, SOT, and EOT would be non printable

Comment: If you are going to do repetitive `Replace` calls like you show, consider using `StringBuilder.Replace` rather than `string.Replace`.  It generates a lot less *garbage* to be collected.

Comment: @jdweng it affects the output yes, but the character itself isn't printed, and that is by definition a non printable character

Comment: @KlausGütter thank you, actually it seems Char.IsControl('') returns true, and Char.IsControl('x') returns false. this is good but then maybe we have a performance issue then. Probably i have long text, it could be problem to check all large string to check. but anyway maybe could be a part of final solution. thanks.

Comment: A non printable character is characters that the printer does not use.  The printer definitely uses the return.

Comment: @jdweng "Non-printing charachters [...] are characters [...] which aren't displayed at printing. [...] The most common non-printable characters are [...] **Tab character** etc." (emphasize mine), the Wikipedia article continues to name a few more. A non printing character is a character the printer doesn't print, as you cannot see the newline character on the resulting, but still uses it and inserts a new line instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [MindSwipe suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63672513/3832970), you may use `\p{C}` to match any control character.

But you do not need to add a lot of code to subtract some characters you might want to keep, use character class subtraction:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(YourTextVariable, @"[\p{C}-[\t\r\n]]+", "");
```

This will match one or more control characters different from tab, carriage return and line feed.

Comment: This is vastly superior to my answer. I also learned something new about Regex, thanks. @cansu you should really accept this answer instead of mine

Comment: You are right @MindSwipe this answer is more accurate actually. Thank you for your contribution also.

Answer (score 2):

Before reading further, please take a look Ryszard Czech's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63676009/9363973) on how to do this without any of the superfluous code of adding newlines back

---

This can achieved by replacing every control character in your string, and luckily Regex has the answer:

```cs
var s = "a \nb" + Convert.ToString((char)0x1b) + Convert.ToString((char) 0x1e);
Regex.Replace(s, @"\p{C}+", String.Empty);
```

`@"\p{C}+"` matches all control characters. Be warned, this will also match new lines (`\n`), meaning your output won't have any newlines as you can see in [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bVELR8) example. If you want your newlines to be kept, you'll have to first split your string into an array, and `Regex.Replace` on each line, and the put them together again. Something like so:

```cs
var lines = s.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    sb.AppendLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"\p{C}+", String.Empty));
}

s = sb.ToString();
```

This leaves a trailing newline, which can easily be removed like so:

```cs
if (sb[sb.Length - 1] == '\n')
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
```

Do this before calling `sb.ToString()`. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HLWOKS) is a dotnetfiddle demonstrating this

Comment: wow, when i try online regex tester it seems working. i will test it in detail so i can check your answer. thanks.

Comment: @cansu I added a link to dotnetfiddle to demonstrate it working

Comment: yes, it seems exception message totally free from bad control characters. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a good old `foreach` is the right way to go.  How about:

```
 private static readonly char[] CharsToReplace =
 {
     '\x02',
     '\x03',
     '\x04',
     '\x05',
     '\x06',
     '\x07',
     '\x08',
     '\x0B',
     '\x0C',
     '\x0E',
     '\x0F',
     '\x10',
     '\x11',
     '\x12',
     '\x13',
     '\x14',
     '\x15',
     '\x16',
     '\x17',
     '\x18',
     '\x19',
     '\x1a',
     '\x1b',
     '\x1c',
     '\x1d',
     '\x1e',
     '\x84',
     '\x86',
     '\x87',
     '\x88',
     '\x89',
 };

public static string ReplaceNonPrintables(string stringToProcess)
{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(stringToProcess.Length);
    foreach (var c in stringToProcess)
    {
        if (!CharsToReplace.Contains(c))
        {
            buf.Append(c)
        }
    }

    return buf.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks, this could be solution if any other ideas do not solve the problem.

Comment: The drawback is that it is O(NxM) (where N is the string length and M is the number of characters to remove).  It might be faster to use a `Hashset`